# How to check .ibd/.isl files are still processing?

Tags: mysql, database, kubernetes, mariadb, galera

Is there any way or a command to know that .ibd/.isl files are processing so that I can hold the liveness probe of kubernetes to kick if there are a large number of files while Galera is processing during recovering.

```
2019-08-22 12:25:04 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 132604203497 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 132604204091 in the ib_logfiles!
2019-08-22 12:25:23 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 33 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:25:40 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 44 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:26:04 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 99 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:26:20 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 176 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:26:36 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 220 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:27:09 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 231 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:27:27 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 264 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:27:47 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 286 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:28:03 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 429 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:28:19 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 561 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:28:35 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 693 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:28:53 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 836 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:29:09 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 957 .ibd/.isl files
2019-08-22 12:29:10 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2019-08-22 12:29:10 140371062364160 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=132604204544
```

Comment: *"How to check .ibd/.isl files are still processing?"* iam assume you mean that you to check if all transactions/qeuries are done with that question?

Comment: Yes I just wanted to know while one galera node is recovering and if log sequence number is not matching then it tries to recover by processing .ibd/.isl files and in my case sath nce data is huge it take lot of time and in the mean time if licenses probe of kubernetes kicks in it restarts the pod. So, I needed to find a way to know that still those files are getting processed so that I can modify my licenses probe script to hold the licenses probe while galera node is processing those file for recovery.

Comment: `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` ? To check for running queries?

Comment: Thanks for the input will check with it. In my last comment it's liveness probe not license probe. Messed up with autocorrect. Sorry about that.

Comment: `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` doesn't seem to give anything while the files are processing but once I have seen a `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` query in that table. So, after going through this query or `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool%'`; can I know if the files are processing ?
Like somewhere in the ROW OPERATIONS of the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` query.